# how to hinge-dissect an 1-omino to 3-omino?

Tags: geometry

Recently I am doing a project about [hinge-dissection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinged_dissection) of poly-omino. A poly-omino is a finite collection of copies of a identical squares such that the interior of their union is connected, and the intersection of two copies is either empty, a common vertex, or a common edge. An m-omino consists of m squares. How to hinge-dissect a 1-omino to an 3-omino, as shown below?
[image: 1-omino][image][image]

Comment: There's no (dissections) tag?

Comment: No dissections tag, only geometry.